# display alt image in IE, because it doesnt display sparkline

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

We use peity to display sparkline graphs.

The code we have JS is: ( I hope it is correct , works fien in chrome and ff )

```
$(function(){
      $(".line").peity("line",{
        colour: "#C6D9FD",
        strokeColour:"#4D89F9",
        strokeWidth:1,
        width:200,
        height:44
      }
```

);
        });

The code to display the sparkline is:

```
<span class="line">1,23,4,7,5,9,10</span>
```

Within IE, it does not display the sparkline, and rather than have this show:

1,23,4,7,5,9,10

I would like to display something else, perhaps a small png image etc. Is this dooable.
Like:

if ie display blah blah blah

Comment: can you provide a link to the sparkline plugin your using? Does it support IE?

Comment: It doesnt support IE.
http://benpickles.github.com/peity/
I had considered using http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/ but we had similar issues, and it is quite heavy

Answer (score 2):

You can write `if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9)`

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain more, in a typical situation ?

Comment: @422: You can use this condition to check whether you're running in a non-decent version of IE.  Inside the `if`, you can use jQuery to display whatever you want.